# What is the best moment to create SQL indexes?

Tags: database, indexing

When starting a project, should SQL indexes be created at the beginning?

I have a project where I haven´t created any indexes yet in production. The table that will grow most has 30000 rows and I have measured the time of the queries against this table creating an index and deleting it afterwards. The times are very similar.

I have decided to postpone the creation of the indexes in production until I notice a reduction of the response time in queries when creating them.

Is my approach correct? Or should I create them now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty deep into the topic of database indexing (it's actually my full-time job, also wrote a book about it (SQL Performance Explained) which is available for free [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)).

In my opinion, indexes should be created at the time you write the query because this is the time you have all the required information needed to decide which indexes to create in your head. In other words, if you do it at that time, it doesn't take you any extra effort. Another reason is that indexing sometimes affects the way you have to write the query so it can actually take benefit of that index.

However, the above statement assumes that you know how indexes work so you can decide which indexes to create. If you don't know that, I'd really suggest to learn about proper indexing first. Again, the book I've written is available for free on the web ([Table of Contents](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents)). According to a recent survey, it takes you about 4-5 hours to read through it. Well-spent time, I'd say.

However, due to the [ludicrous speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vdqpyex9cZs) of modern hardware and vast amount of memory—even cheap commodity hardware—it is absolutely possible that you cannot measure any difference with these small tables (30k is small in DB world) yet. Nevertheless, you because you cannot measure this difference with a timers resolution of maybe 10ms, it doesn't mean the difference isn't there. Further: did you verify that the index was actually used? Are you sure the index you created was a good index for the given query?

Never the less, if the overall system is fast enough for you at the moment, sure you can go on without indexes. The risk remains, however, that it isn't fast enough on the day a major news outlet covers your app. What is supposed to be your best day might turn out to become your worst day :(

You didn't tell us a lot about your app, so I've to do some guesswork. I guess it is more like an OLTP app like an online website (as opposed to BI/OLAP). Although indexes add some overhead to write operations (`insert`, `update`, `delete` and `merge`), this is typically small compared to the benefit they bring to `select` (still assuming OLTP). Sure you can misuse indexes (e.g., creating hundreds on a single table) so that the overhead becomes a major problem too. But adding "a few" indexes on an OLTP table will most certainly not cause any problems due to the maintenance overhead.

Coming to an end: if you already know which indexes are good for your queries (verify it using [explain](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan)), add them now before it is too late. If you are not sure, I'd still suggest to put some effort on that now. If you are not afraid of load peaks taking your app down, go on without indexes.

If you need more help, create a new question containing your query, table & index definitions as well as the explain output and people will be happy to help you figuring out if that index is fine or not.

Comment: Yes, I know how indexes work, but I´m not an expert at all, so I will read your book. Thanks for the link. I like your opinion about creating the indexes in the moment you create the query because it´s the moment when you have more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create them now based on sensible choices: start with primary and foreign keys - thst'll keep your joins fast - then add indexes on single columns you'll be searching on (name, phone, etc) you are using.

Avoid creating multiple column indexes until you have a demonstrated performance problem and you can prove that an index helps. Often, reworking the query will fix the problem better than some complicated index.

The only time I delay creating indexes is if I'm about to load a heap of data and building indexes before loading means a much slower load as the index is updated for every row addition, although some databases allow the index rebuild to be deferred until after the load, so even then there's no point in waiting.